# Django - MySQL database datetime field gets cleared

Tags: mysql, django, forms, datetime, django-models

When I save a value for datetime through a POST request, it gets saved in the database (I verify by logging the value by quering for it afterwards). But when I reload my page, the value is set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
# models.py
class Assignment(models.Model):   
  temp = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
  deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=14))

# views.py
def some_function(request):
  deadline = request.POST['deadline']
  assignment.deadline = datetime.timedelta(int(deadline)) + datetime.datetime.now()
```

When I log the assignment.deadline value throughout this function, it's always what I expect it to be (the current date + whatever the value in the POST request was).
However, when the page reloads, the value is set back to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is in `request.POST['deadline']`? Number of what?

Comment: Do you save the modified assignment at any point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you forgetting to call your assignment's [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) method?